# Какова этимология слова "ШУСТРЫЙ"?

Tags: этимология

Интернет в поиске даёт на этот вопрос весьма пространные ответы.

Answer (score 4):

Из словаря Черных:

**Шустрый** ― в русских словарях с 1852 года, видимо, из говоров, из народной речи. Р - суффикс, как в словах хитрый, быстрый.

Родственные слова ― **шут** (с 11 века) и  **шутить** (16-17 век). Индоевропейский корень от ***seu*** ― кипеть, бурлить, быть стремительным, порывистым.

Общеславянская основа - sutъ. В немецком языке сохранился этот корень: ***sieden*** ― кипеть, кипятить. Также в латышском языке: ***siausti*** ― шутить, проказничать.

В корне ***шуст-*** Сочетание st связано с диссимиляцией согласных: sut-t /sus-t, сначала второе t было суффиксом.

Существование слов с этим корнем в других языках **вызывает сомнение в арготическом происхождении слова.**

Comment: "Существование слов с этим корнем в других языках вызывает сомнение в арготическом происхождении слова." ---- Эти две версии противоречат друг другу. Причем версия об арготическом происхождении менее распространена (насколько я знаю). Тем не менее, она достойна упоминания. Викисловарь приводит ее как одну из возможных.

Comment: У Черных тоже не всё ясно. Слово поздно пришло в язык, из народных говоров, а там оно откуда взялось и из каких говоров. Оно имеет один корень со словами шут, шутить,  но схема образования не очень понятна.  Может быть, шустить - шустрый.

Answer (score 3):

Η.Μ. Шанский, Т.А. Боброва в "Школьном этимологическом словаре русского языка" говорят следующее:

> **Шустрый.** Искон. Суф. производное (суф. *-р-*; ср. мокрый, добрый, хитрый и др.)
>   от той же основы (*шуст-*), что и диал. *шустать* — «очищать от шелухи,
>   мякины, обдирать, просеивать сквозь решето». [...] Диал. *шустать*
>   является вариантом *шастать* того же значения.

Answer (score 3):

ИСТОРИЯ СЛОВ
В. В. ВИНОГРАДОВ

ШУСТРЫЙ
Слово шустрый со значением `бойкий, проворный, ловкий, сметливый, острый`  употребляется в фамильярном стиле современной разговорной речи. Это слово не зарегистрировано ни одним толковым словарем русского языка до «Опыта областного великорусского словаря» 1852 г. Оно и не встречается в языке русской художественной литературы до середины XIX в. В «Опыте областного великорусского словаря» подчеркнута широкая распространенность этого слова в областных крестьянских говорах. Здесь находим такие указания: Шу стер, а, с. м. Молодец. Какой он шустер. Калуж. (...) Шу стро, нар. Бойко, быстро. Шустро бежит лошадь. Моск. Богород. Перм. Усол. Шу стрый, ая, ое, -стёр, стра, пр. Бойкий, расторопный, острый. Шустрый мальчик. Иркут. Моск. Богород. Оренб. Троицк. Перм. Верхот. Ирбит. Перм. Твер. Каш. Краснохолм. Стариц. Том. Якут. Яросл. (Опыт обл. влкр. сл., с. 269).
В. И. Даль в своем словаре также рассматривает слово шустрый как областное (кал. тул. твр. прм. сиб.). Он отмечает еще слово шустрик — `земляная блоха, жучок прыгун, поедающий овощи` (сл. Даля 1909, 4, с. 1486).
**Слово шустрый арготического происхождения. Оно представляет собою перелицовку общерусского слова острый с помощью арготической приставки шу-.** Еще акад. В. И. Ягич в своей работе о тайных языках у славян отметил как один из приемов арготического переодевания лексики искажение слов посредством приставки условного слога или звука или вытеснения ими же начальных звуков слова, например, шутро (`утро`), шурман (`карман`), шусто (`место`), шиблоко (`яблоко`), шилго (`долго`), или кулото (`золото`), курнуться (`вернуться`) и т. п.413 Е. Романов писал о старом арго могилевских нищих («любецком лементе»): «Нищенская молодежь изучает его уже неохотно и, по-видимому, обрекла его на забвение, употребляя по преимуществу ”отверницкую говорку“, т. е. обыкновенный белорусский язык, но с прибавлениями или вставками в слова особых частиц (хер, ку, шу, ша-це, уймуд)»414.
Ср. у Тургенева в рассказе «Стучит» (из «Записок охотника»): «С Филофеем пришло двое его братьев, нисколько на него не п охожих. Маленькие, черноглазые, востроносые, они — точно — производили впечатление ребят ”шустрых“, говорили много и скорого — ”лопотали“, как выразился Ермолай, но старшому покорялись».

Заметка ранее не публиковалась. Сохранилась рукопись (4 стр. разного формата). Печатается по рукописи. — В. Л.
413 Jagič V. Die Geheimsprachen beí den Slaven (Sitzber. d. Wiener Akademie, philos.-histor. Klasse, Bd. 133, 1896). S. 41—63. Ср. В. М. Жирмунский. Национальный язык и социальные диалекты. Л., 1936. С. 156.
414 Романов Е. Р. Очерк быта нищих Могилевской губернии и их условный язык // Этнограф. обозр., 1890, № 4, кн. 7, с. 126.